# Sometimes log in fails with testcafé

Tags: testing, azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, testcafe

I'm working on software testing with testcafe, for a month now, I've been facing a problem which is when I run the test and it clicks on the login button, sometimes it passes and sometimes not, which causes the test to fail. it throws an error

Error details:
Failed to perform a request to the resource at

"mysite.com"
because of an error.
The request header's size is 10242 bytes which exceeds the set limit.
It causes an internal Node.js error on parsing this header.
To fix the problem, you need to add the '--max-http-header-size=...' flag to the 'NODE_OPTIONS' environment variable:

```
  macOS, Linux (bash, zsh)
  export NODE_OPTIONS='--max-http-header-size=20000'

  Windows (powershell)
  $env:NODE_OPTIONS='--max-http-header-size=20000'

  Windows (cmd)
  set NODE_OPTIONS='--max-http-header-size=20000'

  and then start your tests.
```

This happens when I run the tests locally and when in Azure Pipelines.
I tried with **--max-http-header-size=20000** locally and **maxHttpHeaderSize** in the pipeline, but it's not helping.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Note; I also tried with adding a cmd task in task group and I put: set NODE_OPTIONS='--max-http-header-size=20000' but it didn't help.

Comment: To set an environment variable in build agent, you can try creating a pipeline variable `NODE_OPTIONS` and set its value to `--max-http-header-size=20000`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there are two errors at play in this case.

**First:**
There is a mistake in the error message. The command for Windows (cmd) should look as follows:
`set NODE_OPTIONS="--max-http-header-size=20000"` (with double quotes).

**Second:**
There is a known [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2425) with header size. If a header is larger than ~65 KB, it is split into multiple packets. Right now, testcafe only takes the last packet into account when calculating the recommended header size. To run tests, you'll need to find an appropriate max header size that is larger than 80 KB as it's the [default](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/blob/352d2a71a672266f63fa5348fef097ce2db295c9/src/proxy/index.ts#L52) `maxHeaderSize` for TestCafe.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what I should do to get rid of this error?

Comment: I added maxHeaderSize command to the task group as you can see here. This changed nothing.
 .run({
                skipJsErrors: true,
                quarantineMode: true,
                skipUncaughtErrors: true,
                maxHeaderSize: 640000,
                pageLoadTimeout: 30000,
                selectorTimeout: 30000,
                assertionTimeout: 30000

            });

Comment: There is no `maxHeaderSize` option for the [TestCafe run method](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/testcafe-api/runner/run.html). To specify the maximum header size, you need to set the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable before running TestCafe.

Here is how to do it locally in Windows cmd:
`set NODE_OPTIONS="--max-http-header-size=640000" & testcafe chrome ./test.js`

Comment: To run tests in Azure Pipelines, you'll need to define the `NODE_OPTIONS="--max-http-header-size=640000"` environment variable as explained in the [Azure Pipelines documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables).

Comment: How do I know that 640000 is the right value? I just set it randomly, just a big number

Comment: I didn't know how to define it in an environment variable. So I did another thing: in the task group in the pipeline, there was a step like this: node runTestsFile.ts, now it's   set NODE_OPTIONS="--max-http-header-size=640000" & node runTestsFile.ts    but it didn't work.
It worked well locally like you described, so I thought if it maybe works.

Comment: If the tests work, there is no need to tune `--max-http-header-size` further.

As for environment variables in Azure Pipelines, you can set them in the `Variables` dialog when editing the pipeline. To check whether a variable was set successfully, you can add a step with `- script: echo $(NODE_OPTIONS)`. See [this image](https://imgur.com/a/OxWbjI8).